# Вывод с счётчиком и фильтром Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Помогите вывести правильно, если убрать COUNT(ip) AS total, то всё работает отлично, но без счётчика очень печально!

```
 SELECT id, ip, COUNT(ip) AS total, pc, country, date 
    FROM user t
    WHERE id = (
        SELECT max(id)
        FROM user
        WHERE t.ip = ip
    );
```

Изначально я использовал такую систему `SELECT id, ip, COUNT(ip) AS total, pc, country, date FROM user GROUP BY ip DESC`, но после, захотел добавить ещё, чтобы каждая выведенная строка была последняя по id либо по дате, а не старая изначально.

Comment: Честно говоря, не совсем понимаю, зачем вам выводить количество ip , если вы их, собственно, и вытаскиваете с зависимостью от конкретного ip... объясните смысл, пожалуйста.

Comment: Формулируйте постановку задачи, а не только свои попытки эту неозвученную задачу решать...

Comment: `GROUP BY id, ip, pc, country, date` http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Counting_rows.html

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы почти всё правильно сделали. но

1. во вложенном запросе вам надо получить не один (максимальный) `id`, а несколько — по одному для каждого `ip`. это делается как раз директивой `group by` — её надо применить ко вложенному запросу, а не к внешнему. см. первый запрос в примере.
2. для подсчёта количества строк во всей таблице, соответствующих `ip` из получившегося набора, нужен ещё один, отдельный *sql*-запрос. его можно вставить прямо в список получаемых полей (заключив в скобки). см. второй запрос в примере.

вот поясняющий пример:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0eece/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (id int, ip text, d date);

insert into t (id, ip, d) values
   (1, "1", "2017-05-16")
  ,(2, "2", "2017-05-17")
  ,(3, "1", "2017-05-01")
  ,(4, "2", "2017-05-02")
  ,(5, "1", "2017-05-05")
  ,(6, "1", "2017-05-10")
  ,(7, "2", "2017-05-11")
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.id, t1.ip, t1.d
from t as t1
where 
  t1.id in (
   select max(t3.id) from t as t3
   group by t3.ip
  )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0eece/2/0)**:

```
| id | ip |                     d |
|----|----|-----------------------|
|  6 |  1 | May, 10 2017 00:00:00 |
|  7 |  2 | May, 11 2017 00:00:00 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select t1.id, t1.ip, t1.d, 
  (select count(1) from t as t2 where t2.ip = t1.ip) as total 
from t as t1
where 
  t1.id in (
   select max(t3.id) from t as t3
   group by t3.ip
  )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0eece/2/1)**:

```
| id | ip |                     d | total |
|----|----|-----------------------|-------|
|  6 |  1 | May, 10 2017 00:00:00 |     4 |
|  7 |  2 | May, 11 2017 00:00:00 |     3 |
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш труд, всё хорошо работает=)