# SQL query вывод актуального местоположения машины

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица (History_locations)

[image]

Нужно вывести актуальные id_location у машин.
То есть

### id_rolling_car | id_location

1 | 1

---

2 | 2

---

3 | 1

---

Я думаю примерно так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_rolling_car as id_car,
(SELECT HL.id_location FROM History_locations as HL 
 WHERE HL.id_rolling_car = id_car
 ORDER bY HL.date DESC LIMIT 1) as id_location
 FROM History_locations
```

Comment: Ага. И в чём вопрос?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Помочь составить Sql query

Comment: как мы можем помочь, при этом не решая задачу за вас?

Comment: @NickVolynkin я бы не обратился сюда, если бы ничего не делал! Вам мои наработки нужны или что?

Comment: `SELECT id_rolling_car, max(id_location) as id_location FROM `history_locations` group by id_rolling_car`

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Это все же не то, у вас максимальная локация, а не актуальная.

Comment: Ну так говорите что вы подразумеваете под словом актуальное ? Учитывать `date` ?

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan да

Comment: Ну вроде так:
SELECT DISTINCT id_rolling_car as t,
(SELECT K.id_location FROM History_locations as K 
 WHERE K.id_rolling_car = t
 ORDER bY K.date DESC LIMIT 1)
 FROM History_locations

Comment: Это не то.выберите `date` тоже и убедитесь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/667346/178576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы написали в вопросе не годится, потому что при попытке выборки еще и поля `date` все рухнет.По моему надо и это учесть,дабы не столкнуться с тойже проблемой в будущем.

Как вариант:

```
SELECT id_rolling_car, id_location, date
FROM history_locations
WHERE date IN (SELECT max(date) from history_locations GROUP BY id_rolling_car)
ORDER BY id_rolling_car
```

Comment: Хоть и дата мне не нужна, Спасибо большое ;)

Comment: @BigTows Пожалуйста:) Но ведь в дальнейшем могло бы и понадобится.Всегда старайтесь думать на шаг вперед и стараться предугадать проблемы будущего.Удачи !